# Extending abstract class in java

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, abstract-class

Is it possible to create an abstract class having an abstract method which is the constructor of its child class?

For example....

```
abstract class Student {
    abstract void Exam();
}

class Exam extends Student{
    Exam(){
        System.out.println("Total marks=500");
    }
}
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Exam ex = new Exam();
    }
}
```

Comment: no, simple as that

Comment: Is there any way to overcome this issue? @Eugene

Comment: What you want to do exactly?

Comment: what issue? and why do you think you need that? can't you call `super` instead?

Comment: Sounds like an XY Problem. What problem do you want to solve with your approach?

Comment: In fact, my problem isn't solved! If I run my program as in the above mentioned code, I got an error that displays `Exam is not abstract and does not override abstract method Exam() in Student
class Exam extends Student{ ` and your solution wasn't work for me! - @GhostCat

Answer (score 0):

Simply: no.

You see, constructors "look" like methods, but they aren't. See [here](https://www.dummies.com/programming/java/how-to-use-a-constructor-in-java/) for some thoughts on that.

Already the signature tells you that: your abstract method has a **return type**, which a constructor does not have.

If you question is: is there a way within an abstract base class to enforce subclasses to provide a no-argument default constructor? The answer is again: no, that isn't possible. In Java, you can't enforce suche constraints on your child classes.

The only thing that you could do would be something like:

```
 public abstract class Base {
   public abstract <? extends Base> newInstance();
```

or something alike. Meaning: you enforce subclasses to provide a no-argument method that returns an instance of the subclass.

Comment: Even if I remove the return type from the abstract method, it shows an error  `error: invalid method declaration; return type required
    abstract Exam();` - @GhostCat

Comment: Thank You very much! <3 - @Ghostat